# href to modal inside Bootstrap select option

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

Trying to add a href to a modal inside a Bootstrap select. Been going on with this for a few days with no success. Not even sure it can be done, but so far I have this:

```
    <select class="form-control selectpicker" data-dropup-auto="false" name="firm">
        <option>Choose firm</option>
        <?php while ($row = $firm->fetch()) { ?>
            <option><?php echo $row['firm']; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
        <option data-divider="true"></option>
        <option value="#newfirm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#newfirm">New firm</option>
    </select>
```

Is there another way to do this?
Grateful for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use jquery? If yes, how about this:

```
if ($(this).val() == 'Your-option-value') {
    $('#Your-modal-name').modal('show'); 
}
```

For the specified value in select tag, the modal opens...

**Codepen link:** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ypRpZP